# Does int have a max and min value in a SOAP web service?

Tags: java, web-services

If I specify a parameter in my WSDL is of type xsd:int, what is the max and min values for that parameter?  It is dependant on the technology the web service is implemented in?  I am using Java, so am I constrained by the int type in Java or should the web service library (Axis) be handling that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, 32 bits. From [Eric van der Vlist's RelaxNG datatype reference](http://books.xmlschemata.org/relaxng/ch19-77175.html):

```
<xsd:simpleType name="int" id="int">
 <xsd:restriction base="xsd:long">
 <xsd:minInclusive value="-2147483648"/>
 <xsd:maxInclusive value="2147483647"/>
 </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

Additionally, from the [W3C XML Schema Recommendation, Part 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#int):

> int is derived from long by setting
>   the value of maxInclusive to be
>   2147483647 and minInclusive to be
>   -2147483648

Comment: I'm considering leaving my post, though, because I quote text and not XML...:)

Comment: The more the merrier. I'm glad I've found a bit more of a definitive source than the book though :)

Answer (score 4):

According to [this page](http://books.xmlschemata.org/relaxng/ch19-77175.html), xsd:int is:

> ...is the set of common single-size
>   integers (32 bits), the integers
>   between -2147483648 and 2147483647.